# Bootstrap tabs: load NGL viewer into tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have trouble loading the NGL viewer in bootstrap tabs.
It works fine if loaded outside the tabs. However, it does not work if I try loading it within a tab other than the one visible by default.
Any suggestions are welcome.

HTML:

```
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#chartcontainer1" aria- 
    controls="chartcontainer1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart 1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#chartcontainer2" aria- 
  controls="chartcontainer2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="chartcontainer1">
  Some content
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="chartcontainer2">
  Some other content
  <span id="showfilename"></span>
  <div id="viewport" style="width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myTabs a[href="#chartcontainer2"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).show()
  addViewer()

  function addViewer () {
var pdbfile = "rcsb://1CRN"
$('#showfilename').html(pdbfile);
var stage = new NGL.Stage("viewport");
stage.loadFile(pdbfile).then(function (component) {
  component.addRepresentation("cartoon");
  component.autoView();
      });
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: [working outside](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrvxd4z6/)
jsfiddle: [not working (inside tab)](https://jsfiddle.net/zjq0nsLv/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your viewer when the tab is shown.
Use shown.bs.tab event.

I updated your fiddle ;-)